# Java Trident Library and Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm creating a simple board game in Java using Swing with an AI that is supposed to take its turn after the user takes their turn. I want to "pause" the game for about 3 seconds before I allow the AI to take its turn so that the user can see the results of their move. Calling Thread.sleep(3000) also pauses the animations I created using the Trident Animation Library. After the end of the three seconds, the spaces just turn to the color they're supposed to be, no animation done at all.

If anyone can offer any advice, please do. I know I can always add a "Continue" button that the user can press before the AI takes its turn, but I'd like to avoid that step.

Edit: Here's my Single Player panel. It extends GamePanel which is just an abstract class which has a method to update the GUI based on the current board. It also extends JPanel. I think I'm just a little unclear as to where/how to implement the timer to do what I want it to do, whether it's in this class or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running the AI code in a separate thread anyway (you wouldn't want to lock up the UI while running that complicated AI stuff, right?), you want the pause to happen in the AI thread, not the UI thread. Add your Thread.sleep() there.

If you are not currently using a separate Thread for the AI, and this is starting to sound less 'simple' than you intended, have a look at using [Futures and Callables](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures), a nice way of preforming background operations and chaining events to occur when they complete.

Comment: I also tried this solution, making my Player classes implement Runnable and overriding run() in them. I called Thread.sleep() from within my ComputerPlayer class but the animation still pauses, and then the colors just change. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. I'll update my code in a minute.

Comment: Are you creating and starting new Threads for your `Runnable` Players? i.e. `Player runnable = new Player(); Thread playerThread = new Thread(runnable); playerThread.start()` You must always use the `start()` method to actually cause a new thread to start.

Comment: Yes. secondPlayer (that's the AI player) is declared as a class variable of SinglePlayerPanel. When a button is pressed, I create a new thread, passing in secondPlayer just as in the bit of code I posted a few minutes ago. And then I call playerThread.start(). Do I need to include something else? Is playerThread.join() necessary?

Comment: Yes, its the `join` that causing the problem now. Again, it is placing the UI thread in a blocking state preventing any updates.

Comment: Just drop the `join`. I'm assuming there is some kind of a callback in the `play` methods to update the UI once the move is made. In the case of the Threaded AI player you will need to make the update from a `Runnable` passed into the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method. See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Answer (score 4):

Never call `Thread.sleep()` on the Swing event thread or EDT as this will tie up this thread preventing Swing from doing any graphics or interacting with the user. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead. e.g.,

```
  int delay = 3000;
  new Timer(delay , new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // tell AI to do its thing
        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
     }
  }).start();
```

For more on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread or EDT, please read: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I updated my original post with some code. I think I'm just a little unsure where/how to add a timer.

Comment: @d2jxp: not to be trite, but you add it wherever you want your delay. Experiment.

Comment: Not trite :-P I have been messing around with it and I just can't seem to get the animations to finish playing out before the AI makes its move. That's all.

Comment: @d2jxp: You shouldn't even be telling the AI to make its move until after the animations are through.